# Load from Sql Server to Snowflake with SSIS, variant column

Tags: ssis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to load data from local Sql Server to Snowflake with SSIS, no problem with most of the tables but I have one table in Sql with a varchar(max) storing xmldata that I would like to load into a Snowflake variant column. SSIS has a limit of carchar columns on 8000 chars, larger columns it converts them to text streams and that does not work.
Is there a workaround in SSIS to be able to load the content. 
Yes, I know that offloading to local files, upliad them to a Stage is a solution, but I would rather not take that (about 200 000 rows means a time consuming process doing the workaround)

Comment: How are you loading the data to Snowflake using SSIS?  Are you using an ODBC connection?  If so, the "workaround" would actually be MUCH faster.

Comment: yes, it is with the snowflake odbc driver in ssis. I agree that doing it the file way would be faster, but I'll have to do some more coding, no problems but the ssis package is almost finished

Comment: I just found a tutorial that describe how to export VARCHAR(MAX) columns as a byte array, and then use a C# script to transform them back into text. It might be worth taking a look. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5047/import-and-export-varcharmax-data-with-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/

Comment: will do, thanks for the link